# how to put a prompt to stop alarm from ringing and start an alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, alarm

sir, how do i put a prompt to stop the alarm from ringing then start an alertdialog in other class? this code always force close. if i remove the prompt part to stop the clock, the alarm won't stop ringing and the alertdialog shows only once. if it received another message, it won't trigger the alertdialog again. please help me. thanks for help in advance

```
for (SmsMessage msg : messages) {
        if (msg.getMessageBody().contains("alert")) {

            Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
             if(alert == null){
                 // alert is null, using backup
                 alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                 if(alert == null){  
                     // alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
                     alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);               
                 }
             }
             Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(), alert);
             AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             int maxVolumeAlarm = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

             audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolumeAlarm,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);

             r.play();

//prompt
alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alarm Received");

            alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Stop alarm")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    r.stop();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "alarm stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "alarm started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//open alertdialog in other activity        
Intent openInterface = new Intent("proj.receiver.RECEIVERINTERFACE");
            openInterface.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(openInterface);

        }//end if
    }//end for
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you at all but from what i understand:

1. The "r.stop()" inside the Dialog is what makes the alarm stop. So move it from there if you don't want the alarm stopped.
2. The Dialog only opens and alarm only rings when the 'message' is an 'alert' (if), so if you want it to happend in a different message, you must create its own 'if-elseif'.
3. If you want to stop the alarm in another different message (so point 1. and 2.) you MUST move the "Ringtone r =.... " outside the 'if' sentence and/or depending what you want to do, before the 'for' statement.

--

To do it in another Activity, create a Static Class with a Ringtone variable, and when you create the ringtone pass the var to the Static Class to store it. Then when the new Activity opens, get the var from the StaticClass to stop the ringing.
hope it helps.

Comment: my code isn't running, if i leave the r.stop() there, it just force closes.

Comment: did you tried a 'dialog.cancel()' and/or 'dialog.dismiss()' after the 'r.stop()' ?